# How to make a Class Inheritate attributes from a DAL Table and insert

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to make this Business class to inheritate attributes from a **DAL** Type (Client).

**Client** is a Table.

This is the BUS Class, getting attributes from table **Client**

```
    public class BusClient : Client
    {
        public void Insert()
        {
            using(MyBIEntities db = new MyBIEntities())
            {
                db.AddToClients(this); //Here's the problem (don't know what to pass)
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public bool Validate()
        {
            //Validation Rules goes here.
            return true;
        }
    }
```

these are the Webform calls:

```
    try
    {
        BusClient client = new BusClient();

        //Filling properties from Client (table) in the BusClient object all OK.
        client.CityId = int.Parse(ddlCity.SelectedValue());
        client.Name = txtName.Text;
        client.RegisterDate = Convert.ToDateTime("txtDate.Text");

        if (client.Validate())
        {
            client.Insert();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Catching errors
    }
```

The problem is obviously that i can't pass a **BusClient** type to insert.. But I have all those properties already filled, what would be the best way to use them for both `Validate()` and `Insert()` methods?

Another thing: What would be the best practice to avoid Type exceptions/errors (Server-side) that occurs on the form BEFORE I try to Validate() ?

Comment: `MyBIEntities` is probably an `IDisposable` implementation, so you should be wrapping those statements in a `using` block in your `Insert` method.

Comment: What's the purpose of this `BusClient` class and why don't you put those two methods `Insert` and `Validate` directly into the `Client` class (which would solve the problem of inserting the correct type)?

Comment: Client isn't a Class.. it's a Type from a DAL layer

Comment: But `Client` is an entity in an Entity Data Model, isn't it? (Because you are using `db.AddToClients`). What is it if it is not a class? An interface or struct? But this could not be an entity in an EDM, as far as I know. Or do you mean that you cannot modify and add methods to this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have seen you cannot pass in a `BusClient` into `AddToClients`. You would have to create a `Client` from the `BusClient` in your `Insert` method by copying the properties which is quite ugly:

```
public void Insert()
{
    using(MyBIEntities db = new MyBIEntities())
    {
        Client client = new Client();

        client.CityId = this.CityId;
        client.Name = this.Name;
        client.RegisterDate = this.RegisterDate;

        db.AddToClients(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Rethink the design. I cannot see a benefit with deriving a class (`BusClient`) from an Entity (`Client`). If you cannot change the `Client` class you could create either an extension method ...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Validate(this Client client)
    {
        // Run validation rules on client object
    }
}
```

... or a separate class for your validation:

```
public class Validator
{
    public bool Validate(Client client)
    {
        // Run validation rules on client object
    }
}
```

I would also think twice about this separate `Insert` method. While this may work in your example it can cause trouble (or at least become useless) as soon as you have to manipulate a more complex object graph. In such a case you will need one single ObjectContext for the whole operation. You cannot work then anymore with a separate ObjectContext for each INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE an so on.

So, I'd recommend to remove the DB operations from your special class and put this into the main routine. The whole thing could then look like:

```
try
{
    using(MyBIEntities db = new MyBIEntities())
    {
        Client client = new Client();

        client.CityId = int.Parse(ddlCity.SelectedValue());
        client.Name = txtName.Text;
        client.RegisterDate = Convert.ToDateTime("txtDate.Text");

        if (client.Validate())
        // works with the extension method, or with the Validator use:
        // Validator validator = new Validator();
        // if (validator.Validate(client))
        {
            db.AddToClients(client);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Catching errors
}
```

The `BusClient` class doesn't exist anymore in this example.